# DAX Between a date range syntax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to run my `SUMX()` with a `FILTER()` between a date range that I want hard coded.  What I have doesn't work when I add in the between date range component. *See code below:*

```
EnquiryTest = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( '_enquiries,' '_enquiries'[_tsg_clientid_value] = 'accounts[accountid']) &&
    '_enquiries'[Date] => {08/01/2018} && 
    '_enquiries'[Date] =< {08/01/2018},
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
)
```

What is the proper syntax for a between date range?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `{08/01/2018}`, try `DATE(2018,08,01)`.

Comment: The `/` syntax is definitely wrong. What is the error if you use the syntax I suggested?

Comment: EnqAmt = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries, _enquiries[_tsg_clientid_value] = accounts[accountid] && _enquiries[Date] >= DATE(2018,08,01) && _enquiries[Date] <= DATE(2018,08,31) ), _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
)



This works! Thanks for all your help, Alexis Olson